# how to maintain hibernate data consistency between if the two microservices sharing same table of database

Tags: hibernate, microservices, data-consistency

**I'm new to microservices I have a service A , service B Service C are using same database to access the User details which is in Service C. can we have the the same hibernate entity to get the info in service A and Service B , there will be inconsistency of the update operation.
According to me there is three solutions **

1. Have Hibernate Entity of user table in service A and service B both so they cabn access the data
2. Use JDBC and try to get to data from the individual service
3. Call service C to give information which we need to give what user data they need.

Comment: does your services A,B,C using the same database ? make your description more clear !!

Comment: yes both the services are sharing same DB @MohammadMirzaeyan